# What is the default log retention for Grafana Cloud?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

Looking at their [usage-limits documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/billing-and-usage/usage-limits/) it says that the default log retention is 744 hours or 31 days, but when I query the `grafanacloud-usage` data source I see a value of `3024000000000000` I'm not sure what to make of that.

### Query

```
grafanacloud_logs_instance_limits{limit_name="retention_period"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
3024000000000000/24(hours)/60(minutes)/60(seconds)/1000(ms)/1000(us)/1000ns=35
```

I would say that's `3024000000000000 ns` = `35 days`.